# Django override save method for resize image only works forn one function. Why is this happening?

Tags: django, image, model, resize, overriding

I got those two functions in my Model but only the cover_photo one is working.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
  profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/profile_pictures', blank=True, null=True)
  cover_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/cover_photos', blank=True, null=True)
  ...


  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    if self.profile_picture:
      img = Image.open(self.profile_picture.path)

      if img.height > 50 or img.width > 50:
        new_height = 100
        new_width = int(new_height / img.height * img.width)
        img = img.resize((new_width, new_height))
        img.save(self.profile_picture.path)

  


  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    if self.cover_photo:
      img = Image.open(self.cover_photo.path)

      if img.width > 100 or img.height > 100:
        new_width = 600
        new_height = int(new_width / img.width * img.width)
        img = img.resize((new_height, new_width))
        img.save(self.cover_photo.path)
```

If I swap then, only the profile_picture works but the other one stops. Does any one have any idea why this happens? Is there a way to make both works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have only one save method in the class and the 2nd one is always overiding the 1st one. You can put the whole code in one save function:

```
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    if self.profile_picture:
      img = Image.open(self.profile_picture.path)

      if img.height > 50 or img.width > 50:
        new_height = 100
        new_width = int(new_height / img.height * img.width)
        img = img.resize((new_width, new_height))
        img.save(self.profile_picture.path)


    if self.cover_photo:
      img = Image.open(self.cover_photo.path)

      if img.width > 100 or img.height > 100:
        new_width = 600
        new_height = int(new_width / img.width * img.width)
        img = img.resize((new_height, new_width))
        img.save(self.cover_photo.path)
```

Comment: Razenstein! Thank You very much. I would give you a vote for you answer but i have no badges!!! I spend 2 days on it and searching in the internet as well!!!